# Use Taylor’s Theorem with $n = 2$ to give a second proof of the inequality $e^x$ $\ge$ $1+x$ for all real $x$.

Tags: analysis

I've used Taylors theorem to say $e^x$ = $$e^x=1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!}+\dots$$ but not sure where to go from there. I'm not sure what $n$ refers to in the question so not sure how to use that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $f(t) = e^t$.

Pick a point $x \in \mathbf R$.

According to Taylor's theorem there is a point $c$ in between $x$ and $0$ with the property that $$f(x) = f(0) + f'(0)(x-0) + \frac{f''(c)}{2}(x-0)^2.$$ That is to say,
$$e^x = 1 + x + \frac{e^c}{2} x^2.$$

Now observe $\dfrac{e^c}{2}x^2 \ge 0$ regardless of the values of $x$ and $c$.

Answer (score 0):

n=2 typically refers to the term that is second order in your variable, in this case, x. So you want to take the Taylor series to the term $x^2/2$. This is also called the Taylor approximation to Second Order. For the sake of limits, it's usually good to include the follow up term in big O notation.

So here we approximate $e^x\approx 1 + x + x^2/2!+O(x^3)$

From here you should be able to set up an inequality that will establish the proof.

Answer (score 0):

Taylor theorem with remainder
$$f(x)=f(0)+f'(0)x+...+\frac{ f^{(n-1)}(0)}{(n-1)!}x^{n-1}+R_n(x)$$
There are different ways to express this reminder term $R_n(x)$
In your case you have for $f(x)=e^x$ and $n=2$
$$e^x=1+x+R_2(x)$$
You need to prove that $R_2(x)\geq 0$.